# Possible to record the Stage to a movie file?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a multiuser flex application. The application includes voice chat from a streaming server as well as various other dynamic interactions.

I was wondering if it is possible to capture the Experience in the context of a particular user and write it out to a video file for offline playback / sharing / etc...  Something similar to Recording a stream from a Camera object, but only the Stage is the input device... I can't think of any way to do this, so I'm putting it out there for the smart people.  Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found is this: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/ But is it quite old now, so someone must have done something taking advantage of newer features in Flash/AS3/FlashPlayer.